# Can you help simplify my ip range matching regex?

Tags: php, regex, ip-address

I have a regex that will match IP addresses.

it looks like:

`^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|*|25[0-5]-25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]-25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]-2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?-25[0-5]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?-2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?-[01]?[0-9][0-9])$`

which you will mostly recognise from many other posts here on SO.  however I have modded it to  match the range form XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX-XXY

However it now seems a little complex, particularly the final () capture.  I would like some help to simplify this regex if possible.

Just to be clear

`aaaa - not matched

999.1.1.1 - not matched

1.1.1.999 - not matched

192.168.2.1 - matched

192.168.2.* - matched

192.168.2.10-20 - matched`

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I need the existing capture groups as well.

Comment: Why not use a simple `\d+\.\d+\.d+\.\d+` and then a bit of maths to check the correct ranges?

Comment: Because that is lazy. Also i am trying to pass this as a single regex to various form validation methods (Zend, JS, XSD) and there is not always scope to do the maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use optional groups `(?: ... )?` instead and use another grouping for the first 3 parts of the IP?

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
 (?:25[0-5](?:-25[0-5])?|
  2[0-4][0-9](?:-(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]))?|
  [01]?[0-9][0-9]?(?:-(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))?|
  \*)$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qI1cR4)

---

Updated with capture groups

```
^((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\.
 ((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\.
 ((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\.
 (25[0-5](?:-25[0-5])?|
  2[0-4][0-9](?:-(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]))?|
  [01]?[0-9][0-9]?(?:-(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))?|
  \*)$
```

Comment: It is shorter, but has no capture groups to get the elements of the address - i know that is not stated in my original post, I will edit it now!

Comment: @user2010923 I'm wondering whether you actually need capture groups. You can easily check the format of the IP and if it matches, split on period. But I can put a regex in my answer too I guess.,

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\-(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(\*))$
```

As can be seen [here](http://regex101.com/r/yU0dJ1)

Comment: As can be seen in your link this does not match single ip addresses (eg 192.168.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is a bit shorter:

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(\*|(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2}))(\-(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2}))?$
```

See:
http://regex101.com/r/sD9iZ0

Comment: Thank you for this, but it has some strange capture groups.  I know I did not specify the capture groups in the original post, so will edit it now.